# Why won't the button float right?

Tags: html, reactjs, button

I am trying to make the login button float right on the nav bar I made but it is not working and I have searched everywhere for the correct answer. Any ideas?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="nav-bar">
                <h1 style={{color: 'white'}}>To-do list</h1>
                <div style={{float: 'right'}}>
                    {/*The button I am trying to fix*/}
                    <a className="btn btn-dark btn-lg" href="/login">Login</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `h1` is a block level element so your button won't float to the right of it since the `h1` takes up the whole line.

One solution would be to make your `.nav-bar` use the flexbox layout mode:

```css
.nav-bar {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Once you set the layout mode to flexbox, the `float` property no longer has any effect. You can remove that from the element's inline style.

Comment: You should probably add that the float style should be removed too in case that's not obvious to the developer

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!